# Lodash orderBy() gives "TypeError: t is not a function" after minification

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash, uglifyjs

I am using Lodash [orderBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) to sort some data in my app.

```
const sorted = _.orderBy(dataCollection, ['startTime'], ['desc']);
```

This was working great until I created a production webpack build with uglify / minification which then gave the error:

> TypeError: t is not a function

How should I change my code to properly handle obfuscation?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread on the lodash site](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin/issues/128) that describes a similar problem with sortBy(). The solution was to create an function to access the data properties rather than a string property name.

```
const sorted = _.orderBy(dataCollection, [(data) => data.startTime], ['desc']);
```